# Bootstrap - Getting my P (with typing effect) in the middle of a div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, center

I am trying to get my text that has a typing effect to center in the middle of this div but I can't get it to work. Here below you can see my code that I tried using but it would fit the job. It will still display the text at the left of the div.

```
<header class="masthead text-white text-center">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
         <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xl-10 css-typing mx-auto ">
                      <p>
                         Hey! Ik ben 
                      </p>
                      <p>
                         Tom Faas
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
        </div>
</header>
```

The CSS code:

```
.css-typing p {
  border-right: .15em solid white;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.css-typing p:nth-child(1) {
    width: 7.3em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
    animation: type 2s steps(40, end),
    blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(2) {
    width: 7.3em;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
    animation: type2 2s steps(40, end),
    blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid white;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid white;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid white;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid white;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

As you can see in the example I tried using the `mx-auto` tagg but It won't center the text and will still put it at the left of the div.

Answer (score 0):

add below CSS property where you use `mx-auto`. It will center your text.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!